# What does a w | cut -d " " -f 1 - with a grep and sort should do?

Tags: shell-script, grep, sort, cut, w

This is the code I desire to decipher:

```
w | cut -d " " -f 1 - | grep -v USER | sort -u
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
w | cut -d " " -f 1 - | grep -v USER | sort -u
```

The `w` command displays users that are logged on along with some additional information:

```
$ w
 12:59:25 up 50 days, 21:45,  4 users,  load average: 1.02, 1.03, 1.01
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
bill      pts/12   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  12:55    0.00s  0.03s  0.03s tmux
bill      pts/14   tmux(64415).%0   12:55    0.00s  0.05s  0.03s w
dave      pts/18   yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy  Wed09   23:52m  1:15   1:07  vim clear_snapshots.pl
dave      pts/2    yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy  Tue14   23:48m  3.65s  3.65s -bash
```

The `cut -d " " -f 1 -` command extracts the first space-separated column of this (the `-` at the end can be removed):

```
$ w | cut -d " " -f 1

USER
bill
bill
dave
dave
```

`grep -v USER` removes all lines that contain the string `USER`:

```
$ w | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep -v USER

bill
bill
dave
dave
```

`sort -u` sorts its input lexicographically, and removes duplicate lines:

```
$ w | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep -v USER | sort -u

bill
dave
```

---

My guess is that it tries to list the usernames of the users that are currently logged in, as a sorted list.

A simpler way of doing that is by just using the `users` command. `users` will output all logged on users in one line, but you can pipe that through `tr ' ' '\n'` and `sort -u` to get one user per line:

```
users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u
```

This additionally does not depend on the format produced by `w` (the time on the first line of the `w` output may or may not be part of the output of your pipeline depending on whether the current time of day is one or two digits, depending on what implementation of `w` you're using).